# getting a unique values from escaped json lines

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have a huge file with escaped json lines that contains something like this :

```
\"format\":\"html\",\"other\":\"foo\"....
\"format\":\"txt\",\"other\":\"buz\"....
\"format\":\"html\",\"other\":\"bar\"....
```

how can i get all unique values of "format" ?
I need something like

```
\"format\":\"html\"
\"format\":\"txt\"
```

Comment: Those don't look like escaped JSON. Is this how your actual file looks or did you leave out some parts for clarity?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that your file contents are as you show, i.e. the lines start like those three examples (but the values continue on each line, as indicated by the `...`), and given the tag "awk" that you used, how about:

```sh
awk -F, '{formats[$1]=1} END {for (f in formats) print f}' yourfile.dat
```

That said, using `sort` in conjunction with `awk` may be preferable:

```sh
awk -F, '{print $1}' yourfile.dat | sort -u
```

Both these approaches given the data you supply produce this:

```
\"format\":\"html\"
\"format\":\"txt\"
```